# ¿Problema con redirecciones y paramentros .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Soy nuevo con la configuración del .htaccess y las url amigables por lo tanto me han surgido algunas dudas y agradecería bastante la ayuda.

Tengo la siguiente url de ejemplo http://ejemplo.com/pagina_destino.php?page=id-amigable y básicamente lo que hace el archivo pagina_destino.php es recibir el paramento por GET y buscar algunos datos con ese valor en la BD y mostrarlos en la pagina_destino.php.

Si yo quiero hacer una url amigable en mi .htaccess haría algo como esto:

`Rewriterule ^Contrata/(.*)$ pagina_destino.php?page=$1 [L]`

Me he percatado que al momento de pasar la url amigable con una variación en minúsculas y mayúsculas no manda a un error 404, me refiero a lo siguiente:

Esto  http://ejemplo.com/Contrata/Pagina-uno es igual a esto http://ejemplo.com/Contrata/Pagina-uNo

NO se si esto repercute en las búsquedas de google y pueda tomarlas como páginas duplicadas.

Otra cosa que no entiendo es cuando un id no existe ya que no me redirecciona a un 404 si no que la página pagina_destino.php si aparece pero con errores php por no tener el id.

por ejemplo si yo ingreso a http://ejemplo.com/Contrata/Pagina-uno y el id 'Pagina-uno' existe pues no hay problema pero si yo ingreso a http://ejemplo.com/Contrata/Pagina-dos y el indice 'Pagina-dos' no existe en mi base de datos aun así soy mandado a pagina_destino.php (esto los entiendo debido a que cumple la condición del htaccess) pero entonces ¿Cómo hacer que se redireccione a un 404 si el indice pasado por parámetro a pagina_destino.php no existe en la bd?

Comment: en el php si la página no existe podes mostrar un mensaje de que no existe incluyendo la cabecera 404

Comment: Lo que hice fu comprobar si existe: Si existe entonces include ('archivo_con_vista') De lo contrario `header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");  header("Status: 404 Not 
 Found");  include ("httpStatus/404.php");` ¿sería correcto así?

Comment: es una de las formas de manejarlo, considera que si el `404.php` sólo devuelve html estático tal vez te convenga leer un archivo `404.html` imprimirlo y exit/die . en cualquier caso es bueno reutilizarlo agregando [`ErrorDocument 404 rutacompletaynombredelarchivo404.html`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/es/custom-error.html#configuration) al final del `.htaccess`, como es un action puede ser html o php

Comment: aaah ok, muchas gracias